# linq .Contains does not match when equality does match

Tags: c#, linq

The following code does not get any results

```
 var transit = _receiptRepository
            .AcceptanceDetails
            .Where(w => (w.Acceptance.PartyId == partyId || partyId == 0) &&
                         new[] { 3, 4, 5 }.Contains(w.Acceptance.StatusCode));
```

but using an equality operator in place of `Contains` matches as expected

```
var transit = _receiptRepository
            .AcceptanceDetails
            .Where(w => (w.Acceptance.PartyId == partyId || partyId == 0) &&
                         new[] { 3, 4, 5 }.Any(x => x == w.Acceptance.StatusCode));
```

Can someone explain why these are not equivalent?

definition of StatusCode

```
public int StatusCode { get; set; }
```

and from repository code

```
public IEnumerable<AcceptanceDetail> AcceptanceDetails => 
    _appDbContext.AcceptanceDetail.Where(w => w.Closed == null)
                                  .Include(i => i.Acceptance);
```

Comment: Please add the definition of `StatusCode` to your question.

Comment: Is this Entity Framework? What SQL is being submitted to the database for each variant?

Comment: Since `AcceptanceDetails` is `IEnumerable` the queries are evaluated in memory, that is, as LINQ-to-objects. I don't see any reason why the results would differ, neither can I reproduce this in a similarly shaped query. Neither when returning `IQueryable<AcceptanceDetail>`, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried adding a 'int' instead of an anonymous type? like:

    ```var transit = _receiptRepository
            .AcceptanceDetails
            .Where(w => (w.Acceptance.PartyId == partyId || partyId == 0) &&
                         new int[] { 3, 4, 5 }.Contains(w.Acceptance.StatusCode)); ```

Comment: @ramk, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that Expression Trees are interpreted and do not have the same behavior as compilation.   I believe the expression tree is not translating your array correctly.  You should extract that to a variable first.

```
var statuses = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };

var transit = _receiptRepository
        .AcceptanceDetails
        .Where(w => (w.Acceptance.PartyId == partyId || partyId == 0) &&
                     statuses .Contains(w.Acceptance.StatusCode));
```